# Pokemon in Pixelmon server don't appear when I send them out?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-pixelmon

I have a Pixelmon server for my friend and I to play on. It's been working fine for the last week, but when I came on it today, and I threw out my Pokemon it wouldn't show up. It would say *"Sent out Charizard"*, but nothing happened. 
How do I make my Pokemon appear? Any help would be appreciated.

I play on Mac, and I run the server. The server has 3 GB of RAM.

Comment: Most likely, lag (or slow system speed). Have you tried with other modpacks yet? Usually this happens when the server hasn't tell the client that "Your pokemon you spawned is *here*". Also worth noting that chat and the world is two different streams of information. (You could do `//set` and the chat would say the operation is complete despite no changes in the world)

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is just lag, if it is serious lag, re-log onto your game, or maybe even restart the computer.

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes happens to me. For me, if you throw it too close to you it won't appear. So try throwing it farther.